# probability and mathematics

Tags: statistics

In a sequence of n independent fair coin tosses, what is the expected number of occurrences
of the pattern HTH (consecutively)? Note that overlap is allowed, e.g., HTHTH
contains two overlapping occurrences of the pattern.

Comment: I wonder why the down vote was given. Though, it would have been better if you had shared your thoughts and progress in the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You will have $ n-2$ consecutive triples to check in any string of length $n$. The probability that any triple is "HTH" is 1/8. So the expected number of "HTH" triples is $\frac{n-2}{8}$.

UPDATE: It was pointed out that my original calculation above was incorrect. My answer is correct, but my original reasoning was flawed. Let give a correct and more detailed answer.

Let $X$ be the random variable of the total number of occurrences of "HTH" in my string of $n$ coin flips. Let $X_i$ be the indicator random variable such that "HTH" occurs for the first time in the $i$th position. Then $P(X_i=0)=\frac{7}{8}$ and $P(X_i=1)=\frac{1}{8}$ and we conclude that $E(X_i)=0\cdot\frac{7}{8}+1\cdot\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{8}$. Clearly $X=\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}X_i$ so that by the linearity of expectation we have:
$$
E(X)=E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}X_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}E(X_i)=\frac{n-2}{8}.
$$

Comment: I would like to see a bit more explanation.  (The events are not independent, but this works anyway...)  Or maybe Hao should consider this a hint and finish the proof.

Comment: I see your point. My calculation is the expected number of "HTH" in repeating a 3-coin toss $n$ times.

Comment: Actually my original answer is correct. See my edits.

Comment: It is correct.  Unlike products, which require independence, the expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations even without independence.

Comment: Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.

Comment: I agree with the I.I.D. part, could you explain  why the total number is N-2?

Comment: We write out the results of our $n$ coin tosses from left to right and then we are checking for the "HTH" pattern starting in each of $n$ positions. It is impossible for "HTH" to show up in either the $n-1$ or the $n$ position since there are only two coin tosses available to check in the $n-1$ position and only one position to check in the $n$ position.